# Bison : float = int / int

Tags: bison

I am learning Bison/Flex and I do not understand how can I force the $$ type to be a float in .y file.
**scanner.l** file

```
%{
#include "token.h"
%}
%%
[0-9]+ { return TOKEN_INT; }
"/" { return TOKEN_DIV; }
%%
int yywrap() { return 1; }
```

**parser.y** file

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
void yyerror(char const *s) {} ;
extern char *yytext;
%}

%token TOKEN_INT
%token TOKEN_DIV

%%
program : expr
    {
        float div_result;
        div_result=$1; 
        printf("In pgm %f \n",div_result);
    } ;
expr : factor TOKEN_DIV factor
    { 
        printf("In expr %f \n",(float)$1/(float)$3); 
        $$ = (float)$1 / (float)$3;
    } ;
factor: TOKEN_INT { $$ = atoi(yytext); } ;
%%

int main() { yyparse(); }
```

In expr rule, the printf output is right. For example, if the input is 7/3, the print output is 2.333333. But in program rule, the printf output is 2.000000.
 It seems that $$ in expr rule or $1 in program rule is int type. Right ? and Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `int` is the default type for all semantic values unless you specify something else. See the [bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Value-Type) for details.

As indicated in that link, it could be as simple as adding

```
%define api.value.type {double}
```

Don't use `float`. The "normal" floating point representation in C is `double`. `float` is far too imprecise to be useful for most purposes; it should only be used for very specific applications in which the imprecision is tolerable.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Should all the semantic values have the same type ?

Comment: @stef1611: that depends on you. Read the linked chapter in the bison manual and study the examples. (But remember that a non-terminal is a lot like a variable: different non-terminals can have different types, but a non-terminal has just one type. Just like a variable.)